# Pivoting a column and showing data according to count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have following table:

[image]

I wanted to pivot month column and show count of data according to groups of >10,<=06,etc.

Means wanted to show how many counts for >10 in Jun, jan

As folows:

```
Gruppi Min (GG Flusso/Decorrenza-->Out)   Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun

>10                                        5   2  1   0    8  2

<=06                                       2  8   1   7    9  33
```

**I Tried as follows:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(3), [data out (no val#vuoto)], 0) month, 
               ( [gruppi min (gg flusso/decorrenza-->out)] ) 
        FROM   dbpratiche 
        WHERE  compagnia = 'GENERALI INA ASSITALIA' 
               AND stato = 'OUT ATTIVATA' 
               AND [data out (no val#vuoto)] > '01-01-2012') TLB 
       PIVOT ( Count([gruppi min (gg flusso/decorrenza-->out)] ) 
             FOR tlb.month IN([jan], 
                              [feb], 
                              [mar], 
                              [apr], 
                              [may], 
                              [jun]) )PVT
```

but given me following result:

[image]

Its not grouping according to >10,<=06,etc. and showing overall count.

where i am making mistake?

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(SELECT 1 CntCol, [Gruppi Min (GG Flusso/Decorrenza-->Out)], [month]
FROM #X) TLB
PIVOT
(
COUNT (CntCol)
FOR TLB.[month] IN
( [jan],[feb],[mar],[apr],[may],[jun] )
) AS pvt
```

You need to add a column that should be counted.

Look at the complex example here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Change your code to this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT 1 CntCol, CONVERT(CHAR(3), [data out (no val#vuoto)], 0) month, 
               ( [gruppi min (gg flusso/decorrenza-->out)] ) 
        FROM   dbpratiche 
        WHERE  compagnia = 'GENERALI INA ASSITALIA' 
               AND stato = 'OUT ATTIVATA' 
               AND [data out (no val#vuoto)] > '01-01-2012') TLB 
       PIVOT ( Count(CntCol) 
             FOR tlb.month IN([jan], 
                              [feb], 
                              [mar], 
                              [apr], 
                              [may], 
                              [jun]) )PVT
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add an autoincrement field to your dbPratiche table(for example id), and then try this code:

```
    select * from 
    (
       select [id], [month],  [gruppi]   
       from dbPratiche 
    )as s
    pivot
    (
       COUNT ([id])
       for month in(jun, sep, jul, may, aug)
    )as PVT
```

Answer (score 1):

check this may help you

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        year(invoiceDate) as [year],left(datename(month,invoicedate),3)as [month], 
        InvoiceAmount as Amount 
    FROM Invoice
) as s
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Amount)
    FOR [month] IN (jan, feb, mar, apr, 
    may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec)
)AS pivot
```